# Is there a good comparison of the different Entity Framework 2.0 code generators?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, poco

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587280/entity-framework-poco), I'm wondering if anyone has found a good comparison between the [POCO Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313) and the 1.0esque Entities/Context.  Why should I use one over the other?  Or, what criteria should I be evaluating on my project to make my decision?

I once thought that POCO's were less work for mvc/wcf/databinding.  But it seems a more customized object really suits the needs better. ie viewmodels or dto's.  Or is this point. They were created to shortcut development with less than ideal implementations?

Assume I'm familiar with the [adonet blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/), which should be mandatory reading.